# Refactor out "Stop running this script?" error in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I've been tweaking this and that and the other in an attempt to get the "Stop running this script?" error to go away in IE7 - the browser all users are required to use at this time :P  I've tried several improvement attempts; all of them have caused the script to stop working, instead of running long.  I've tried using setTimeout(), with no luck.  It's possible I didn't do it correctly.  Can anyone suggest ways to improve this to make it more efficient (and get that dang long running script message to go away)?

Here's the code:

The HTML:

```
<div class="changeView" style="float:right;">Show All...</div>
<div id="accordion" style="width: 99%;">
    <% foreach (var obj in Model.Objects) { %>
        <h3><a href="#"><span class="title"><%:obj.Id%></span><span class="status" style="font-size:75%"> - <%:obj.Status%></span></a></h3>
        <div id="<%:obj.Id %>">
            <div class="loading"><img src="<%=Url.Content("~/Content/Images/ajaxLoader.gif") %>" alt="loading..." /></div>
        </div>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

Then we have an onclick function to start it off...

```
$(function () {
    $(".changeView").click(function () {
        var divText = $(this).html();
        var src = '<%=Url.Content("~/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif")%>';

        if (divText == "Show All...") {
            $(this).html("Show Filtered...");
            $('#accordion').accordion('destroy');
            $('#accordion').empty();
            $('#accordion').addClass("loading");
            $('#accordion').append('Loading Information...<img src="' + src + '" alt="loading..." />');
            changePartialView("all");
        }
        else {
            $(this).html("Show All...");
            $('#accordion').accordion('destroy');
            $('#accordion').empty();
            $('#accordion').addClass("loading");
            $('#accordion').append('Loading Information...<img src="' + src + '" alt="loading..." />');
            changePartialView("filter");
        }
    });
});
```

Next the changeView function is called:

```
//change view and reinit accordion
function changePartialView(viewType) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<%:Model.BaseUrl%>" + "ToggleView",
        data: "Type=<%:Model.Target%>&Id=<%:Model.Id%>&view=" + viewType,
        success: function (result) {
            $('#accordion').empty();
            $('#accordion').removeClass();
            for (var index = 0; index < result.Html.length; index++) {
                $('#accordion').append(result.Html[index]);
            }
            var $acc = $("#accordion").accordion({
                collapsible: true,
                active: false,
                autoHeight: false,
                change: function (event, ui) {
                    var index = $acc.accordion("option", "active");
                    if (index >= 0) {
                        var clickedId = ui.newHeader.find("a").find(".title").text();
                        getRequirements(clickedId);
                    }
                    else {
                        // all panels are closed
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, err) {
            alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
            alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
            alert("Error in ajax: " + result);
        }
    });
}
```

**Note:** The result.Html returns a generic List of formatted HTML, one for each panel of the accordion.  With the exception of the long running script error message, everyone works pretty sweet.

**Clarification of returned value:**  The result.Html consists of about 200-250 instances of these strings:

```
"<h3><a href=\"#\"><span class=\"title\">" + obj.Id +
"</span><span class=\"status\" style=\"font-size:75%\"> - " + obj.Status + count +
"</span></a></h3><div id=\"" + obj.Id + "\"><div class=\"loading\"><img src=\"" +
Url.Content("~/Content/Images/ajaxLoader.gif") + "\" alt=\"loading...\" /></div></div>")
```

Comment: The first thing I'd try would be to create a new `<div>` element before the loop that appends the ajax results, append the results to *that* instead of the real DOM, and then append the `<div>` when finished.

Comment: what is `result.Html`? I'm wondering if you are appending a long string, character by character...

Comment: I think that's what @evan just submitted - see my response.

Comment: @MrOBrian - see the note at the end, it explains what's being returned.

Comment: The for loop in your success callback is the only place I see that the browser could get stuck. If you are returning the data as JSON, IE7 might not understand it correctly. Try doing `alert(result.Html.length)` and see what IE7 says as compared to other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
        for (var index = 0; index < result.Html.length; index++) {
            $('#accordion').append(result.Html[index]);
        }
```

Appending a lot of nodes one-at-a-time into the DOM is slow, one way you might be able to speed this up is to insert them all into an unattached node and then move them all at once when you're done:

```
        var holder = $('<div></div>');
        for (var index = 0; index < result.Html.length; index++) {
            holder.append(result.Html[index]);
        }
        $('#accordion').append(holder.children());
```

Comment: I changed it as you suggested, but I still get the message.  I also factored out all the accordion selectors into a single call in both the click function and the change view function (var $acc = $("#accordion");) and then used the variable for all subsequent calls.  Thought it might help.

Comment: you're not giving us a lot to work with, to be honest. That error just means something's taking a really long time. It could be anything. (You don't have $.ajax configured to be synchronous, do you?) Try profiling your script with Chrome's web developer tools. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/12/javascript-profiling-chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: another thing you could try is to just assemble the HTML on the server and then insert it with $('#accordion').html(assembledHTML)

Comment: Getting any third party tools around here is like pulling teeth.  It would take a couple weeks at best to get it.  Really conducive to cutting edge development :P  As for $ajax being configured to be synchronous, pretty sure I haven't...

Comment: I tried that too.  Figured having an array of sorts would give me places to insert a setTimeout, but I couldn't get that to work either.

Comment: Surely you have a computer somewhere in your possession that you can install Chrome on and use to test this. It's starting to sound like the inserting nodes isn't the bottleneck. You need to find what the bottleneck is, or you'll never fix this. If you can't get the tools you need to do your job I'd find a new job, but this isn't the place for that discussion.

Comment: Closest thing I have is Fiddler2, which doesn't seem to give a lot of info about time profiling.  Using that, it shows that there is only one request, and it lasts just under 16 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Change the server to return data instead of lots of HTML. Use a client-side templating solution.
Then, once you have an array, you can just update the display asynchronously (like with the `setTimeout` you mentioned)

You only have two dynamic things in that big HTML string, pretty wasteful.

Or return less items?

Comment: Yeah, that's how I started.  I was returning just the data and building the Html in the page for each panel, but I was still getting the script error.

Comment: that's where the setTimeout comes in, if you don't do it in one long-running operation, there would be no alert. Just work on a subset of the array (like 30 at a time), then use setTimeout to re-run the function.

Comment: Can you toss up an example?  I tried doing that and it just ended up breaking the accordion.

Comment: I tried to make it simple - http://jsfiddle.net/4UHk7/ (yeah, I should probably mention I don't know how the accordion works - this is just the crude logic)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.  What exactly does the delay param do?

Comment: controls the delay between runs of the function, I set it to 200ms so the updates will be easily visible, you may want to change it to something smaller)